# How to set the default error pages for a basic Webrick server?

Tags: ruby, webrick

I have a very basic webrick server running for the admin pages of an embedded device.  We just added basic authentication to the device and it works great, but you get the generic "unauthorized" message back like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
    WEBrick::HTTPStatus::Unauthorized
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-12-25) at
     192.168.1.1:1234
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Does anyone know how to override this to return a static HTML file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it looks like [`httpresponse.rb`](https://github.com/nahi/webrick/blob/f92714c5a38d9ff0bbed5c63c053028c95876189/lib/webrick/httpresponse.rb#L286-L289) has a "hook" called `create_error_page`:

```
  if respond_to?(:create_error_page)
    create_error_page()
    return
  end
```

So, if you add your own Ruby method called `create_error_page` in `WEBrick::HTTPResponse`, you can set your own markup:

```
module WEBrick
  class HTTPResponse
    def create_error_page
      @body = ''
      @body << <<-_end_of_html_
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>#{HTMLUtils::escape(@reason_phrase)}</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>#{HTMLUtils::escape(@reason_phrase)}</H1>
    <HR>
    <P>Custom error page!</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
      _end_of_html_
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you have access to variables like `@reason_phrase` and `ex.code`. In your case, you can use `ex.code` (eg: `401`) to set different content if you wish.

Here is a full example that you can run in an `irb` console that displays a custom error page (note that it assumes you have a directory called `Public` in your file system):

```
require 'webrick'

module WEBrick
  class HTTPResponse
    def create_error_page
      @body = ''
      @body << <<-_end_of_html_
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>#{HTMLUtils::escape(@reason_phrase)}</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>#{HTMLUtils::escape(@reason_phrase)}</H1>
    <HR>
    <P>Custom error page!</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
      _end_of_html_
    end
  end
end

root = File.expand_path '~/Public'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => root
trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

When you go to `http://localhost:8000/bogus` (a page that does not exist), you should see the custom error page, like so:

[image]

Hope it helps! :-]